# My Router Internet IP is different from my public IP

Tags: networking, nat

I am running a ddns client on Ubuntu for Nextcloud server, however my ISP has done something to the router so internet IP showing in the router is different from my public IP which causes an issue when ddclient updates the IP of my domain.

I have tried to contact my ISP but they want me to pay a huge amount for a fixed IP.

Is there any solution for this?

My router model is HG8245Q2.

[image]

*PS: The IP shown in the image is just an example.

Note: I tried this on a another router model HG8245Q, and it gives me the same IP on both router and google. so no issue on the old router model.

Comment: Your residential ISP is using CGN, and it doesn't care that breaks your server because your residential terms of service prohibit service to the Internet. Search on [su] for `CGN` for what is happening.

Answer (score 14):

The IP address you see in your router is just another internal IP address from private range 10.x.x.x

This means your router is not connected directly to the internet but to another subnet of your ISP. And only this subnet is connected to the internet over another router (with NAT) and this router has a public IP address.

This is standard behavior with most of ISP because they have limited count of public IP addresses. If you need public IP, you have to pay for it, change ISP who gives you one for free or try some edge case solution like rent VPS server and make VPN tunnel to your home router (this requires advanced networking skills)

Comment: i noticed that the internal ip has not changed since 3 days and i could appoint it to my domain, but i dont know when they will decide to change it.

im setting up this server for my company, but i have tested it at home, same internal ip there i can find it on google. so if they use a subnet it could be vary from network to network.

Comment: Is a private ip by vpn provider a good solution for my case? If so any suggested good vpn provider.

Comment: The most straightforward solution is to pay for a static public IP address to your ISP.

VPN will decrease your internet speed and requires maintenance, as well as you have to pay somebody else for this service. 

If you will point a domain to the internal IP address, it will work only for people on the same subnet (inside of the company) but everyone else from the internet (outside) will not be able to connect

Comment: Yeah, I thought my router has public IP, but after some checks I found it is internal to ISP. Router shows 10.x.x.x in status page, Google shows 103.x.x.x

Scratched my head for hours in searching why Port Forwarding is not working :D

Answer (score -2):

Maybe DDNS comes in handy for you. You can opt for free DDNS services like [DynDDNS](https://www.dynu.com/en-US/) or [NoIP](https://noip.com).

Steps [I personally prefer noip.com ]:

1. Create a Free Account
2. Choose a hostname(We can say a domain name pointing towards ur system IP)
3. Download their desktop client(To sync your Dynamic IP with the hostname you selected)
4. Boom it's done! Use that hostname instead of IP wherever needed, traffic will be redirected to your system. Just take care of port forwarding and firewall settings.

Comment: He is already using a DDNS provider. The problem is that IP address shown to the modem/router is not his real external IP.